# Display contents of a string in html table using preg_match and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that contains ASL of users  seprated by a pipe

my string :

```
  Jack:22:m:london,uk|john:20:m:otava, canada|ketty:26:f:san fransisco|patricia:19:f:guatemala city
```

my regex :

```
 /([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+):([A-Za-z]):([^|]+/
```

I want to display these asls on my wepage in html table.

```
jack 22 m london,uk
john 20 m otava canada
```

my code:

```
    $users="Jack:22:m:london,uk|john:20:m:otava, canada|ketty:26:f:san fransisco|patricia:19:f:guatemala city";

  echo preg_replace('/([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+):([A-Za-z]):([^|]+)/','<table border="1"><tr><td>$1</td><td>$2</td><td>$3</td><td>$4</td></tr></table>',$users);
```

It's working as expected  but the pipe | is being included in output .

You can see the live demo of my code on https://eval.in/480802

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data only contains `|` as user separator, and `:` as user details separator, you can just use 2 `explode`s like this:

```
$users="Jack:22:m:london,uk|john:20:m:otava, canada|ketty:26:f:san fransisco|patricia:19:f:guatemala city";
$usr_arr = explode('|', $users);
foreach ($usr_arr as $usr)
{
    $parts = explode(':', $usr);
    echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>'.$parts[0].'</td><td>'.$parts[1].'</td><td>'.$parts[2].'</td><td>'.$parts[3].'</td></tr></table>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Oepee7)

Output:

```
<table border="1"><tr><td>Jack</td><td>22</td><td>m</td><td>london,uk</td></tr></table>
<table border="1"><tr><td>john</td><td>20</td><td>m</td><td>otava, canada</td></tr></table>
<table border="1"><tr><td>ketty</td><td>26</td><td>f</td><td>san fransisco</td></tr></table>
<table border="1"><tr><td>patricia</td><td>19</td><td>f</td><td>guatemala city</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I ended up using your Explode() function . its easier then regex. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I also find it easier than a regex in this case. If you ever have any issue with this solution, feel free to drop a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

When using preg_replace, your regex will not touch the `|` character at all, thus simply leaves it there.
A simple solution is to consume a single `|` character if it exists at the end of your current regex pattern:

`/([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+):([A-Za-z]):([^\|]+)\|?/` (the `\|?` was added at the end)

Remember that the `|` character should be escaped too (`\|`).

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I will simply replace pipes with `</td></tr><tr><td>` and semi-colons with `</td><td>`:

```
$users="Jack:22:m:london,uk|john:20:m:otava, canada|ketty:26:f:san fransisco|patricia:19:f:guatemala city";

echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>'
   . strtr($users, ['|'=>'</td></tr><tr><td>', ':'=>'</td><td>'])
   . '</td></tr></table>';
```

(Note: I don't think you want a different table for each record, so I putted all in the same table with a row for each record).